# Android: ArrayAdapter introducing selected data into database

Tags: android, checkbox, adapter

Hei!

I have a listview with textviews and checkboxes and i`m trying to add into database the elements which have the checkbox checked.

The problem is that when i check an element on the interface is displayed correctly but in database is inserted another element (usually one from the first elements in the list).

I`ve no idea why is this happening, could you please help me?

Here is some code from my ArrayAdapter where the list is displayed and the elements are inserted into database.

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      final Databases db = new Databases(context);

      View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
      view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
      final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
      viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
      viewHolder.checkbox
          .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
              Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                  .getTag();
              element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
              db.open();
                if(element.isSelected()){

                    Log.v("Databases", "Insert in DB " + list.get(position).getName());

                    db.createEntryTable3(element.getName(), "2", "1");


                }


                 db.close();
            }
          });

      view.setTag(viewHolder);
      viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
      view = convertView;
      ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

    return view;
  }
```

Comment: move the onCheckedChangeListener outside your if(convertView == null){ .. }

Comment: Avoid using holder for checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, your problem arises since you do not have "not-selected" else-case here:

```
if(element.isSelected()){
  Log.v("Databases", "Insert in DB " + list.get(position).getName());

  db.createEntryTable3(element.getName(), "2", "1");
}
```

Comment: I`ve also tried having not-selected case but this is not the problem.